# How do I set allowed extensions for a managed_file form field?

Tags: 7, forms

Not having any luck find this in Drupal documentation or developer examples.  I need to set a managed_file form field to only allow zip files in a Drupal 7 custom module.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$form['picture']['file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('picture'),
  '#description' => t('Allowed extensions: gif png jpg jpeg'),
  '#default_value' => (isset($foo->picture->fid) ? $foo->picture->fid : ''),
  '#upload_location' => variable_get('picture_upload_location'),
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    // Pass the maximum file size in bytes
    'file_validate_size' => array(MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024*1024),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I tried the file_validate_size, but it does not working.

Comment: It doesn't work for me to.

Comment: wehre come from $foo?

Comment: It seems like validation does not happen automatically if you save a file manually. I had to do it like this: `$file = file_save_upload('file', $form['picture']['file']['#upload_validators']);`

Comment: This works also in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using Drupal 6 or Drupal 7, but in Drupal 6 you would choose:

- **Admin** > **Content** > **Content Types** > [Your Content Type] > **Manage Fields** > [Edit your file field] and look for the field setting of *"Permitted upload file extensions"*
- In that field, enter *zip*

Drupal 7 is probably similar. Look for *Content Types* under **Admin** > **Structure**.

Comment: Drupal 7, sorry for the omission. I'm using a managed_field form item in a custom module, so the admin isn't going to help.  I need a programming solution.

Comment: I believe you can use #upload_validators:  

$form['file']['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0] = 'png jpg gif pdf';

Comment: NEAR DARK wins it.  It took pasting in that line to realize that I had a typo in my original form item array.  So basically, this is a well documented feature of the form api that I wasn't getting because of a spelling error. Sorry guys.

Comment: Note: there is no managed_file form field in Drupal 6, only file. Source: [Drupal 6 Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)